# Best ways of centralising a div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I'm just curious as to what the best way is of aligning a div centrally (vertically and horizontally) inside another div. This example features a red div which I want to vertically & horizontally centre inside the div with the background picture.

What is the best way of doing this so it automatically adapts when resizing the browser window & displaying on mobiles?

The following methods fail:

- position:relative; & top: 50%; - only the very top of the div is centralised but not the rest. Adding a negative margin-top fails because it applies it to the parent element
- margin: 25% auto;
- vertical-align: middle;
- justify-content: center; - presumably only applies to flexboxes

Here is the code:

```css
body{
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#first{
    width:100%;
    height:550px;
    background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/30627/pexels-photo-30627.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

#central{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    
    /*
    
    Why DO THESE FAIL:
    
    position:relative; & top: 50%;
    
    margin: 25% auto;
    
    vertical-align: middle;
    
    justify-content: center; - presumably only applies to flexboxes
    
    */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      
      <div id="first">
        <div id="central"></div>
      </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: Add `position: relative` to #first and add `top:50%;
    left:50%;
  transform:translate( -50%, -50%);
  position:absolute;`  to #central
[FiddleHere](https://jsfiddle.net/L9uxv0vk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is using flexbox. Check this amazing [post about flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

The css of the parent div has to be sth like that:

```
.first {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```